# Adobe PhoneGap Build fails on cordova-plugin-file

Tags: cordova

There's a simple Cordova project with cordova-plugin-advanced-http plugin, which uses core cordova-plugin-file plugin. When I compile Android project locally, everything works fine. But the same project compiled with Adobe PhoneGap Build fails. The log says:

```
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file@>=2.0.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" at "5.0.0" for android 
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. 
cordova-android: 6.1.2, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0 
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-file' for android
```

How to fix that? Locally I use the latest Cordova 7.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below listed plugin with Cordova 7.1.0 for files transfer.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.5.0" />
```

We need to use both and its working fine. Please have a look and let me know.